# Is it possible to make circle markers with font awesome icon in Rshiny?

Tags: r, leaflet, shiny

Great R Gurus,

Is there any possible way to make circle markers with font awesome icons in the following example:

```
df.20 <- quakes[1:20,]

getColor <- function(quakes) {
  sapply(quakes$mag, function(mag) {
    if(mag <= 4) {
      "green"
    } else if(mag <= 5) {
      "orange"
    } else {
      "red"
    } })
}

icons <- awesomeIcons(
  icon = 'ios-close',
  iconColor = 'black',
  library = 'ion',
  markerColor = getColor(df.20)
)

leaflet(df.20) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(~long, ~lat, icon=icons, label=~as.character(mag))
```

I wish to achieve something like [this](https://github.com/lvoogdt/Leaflet.awesome-markers) but with circle markers.
Your time to answer is highly appreciated...

Comment: Is it not possible to use `addAwesomeMarkers()` instead of `addCircleMarkers()`for you?

Comment: What you could do is download png copies of the icons you want to use and make a icon list as specified in the leaflet for r documentation.  Then plot circles over the icons.  But it does not look like you can do it with the addAwesomeMarkers().

Comment: @BigDataScientist, thanks for your comment. My data has over 14000 points on NZ map. Circles are colored and sized by different data attributes and icon would help to bring another dimension on the map. addAwesomeMarkers() is not a good option to handle these things.

Comment: @Ian Wesle, thanks for your comment. I did consider that too. However, it is not feasible for the team of 60 sales people (color of the circle) with 10 types of customers (icon).